# Inserting without duplicates is not working as expected

Tags: sql, hive

I'm attempting to add to a table new rows where there is no clash in a particular field, however every time I try and add rows with duplicate data, those rows are added and the table grows. This should not be case. I am using one field named: `event_id`, as the key that I want to ensure does not appear again, but each time, I'm getting the rows added.

The insert statement looks like this:

```
insert into existing_table
select distinct event_id
  , event
  , cs.pid as cs_pid
  , context_page_url
  , try_cast(concat(cs.year, "-", cs.month, "-", cs.day) as string) as event_date
  , split_part(cs.context_page_url, '|', 0) as stem
from target_table cs where year=2023
```

So if `event_id` appears in `existing_table` then ignore it.

No growth in the table size.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `not in ()` in existing_table.

```
insert into existing_table
select distinct event_id
  , event
  , cs.pid as cs_pid
  , context_page_url
  , try_cast(concat(cs.year, "-", cs.month, "-", cs.day) as string) as event_date
  , split_part(cs.context_page_url, '|', 0) as stem
from target_table cs where year=2023 
and event_id not in (select event_id from existing_table) -- ensures event ID doesnt exist.
```

Comment: This is doing something very odd. The NOT IN does not appear to work at all. I've tried some variants. This always returns no rows and therefore no new data is added to the existing table. I'm doing this in Hove - could there be some strange effects?

Comment: no it shouldnt be any different in hive or anhywhere. can you pls check if data type in both tables are same and then fire only select statement and see whats happening. 0 row means all event ids exists in both tables - nothing new to insert